# Code Igniter: Js file is included successfully, the script not working

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, include-path

I'm working on Code Igniter framework.
I have a php file in:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\MSPN\APPLICATION\views\Pengguna\yes.php
```

I also have js file in:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\MSPN\TAMPILAN\js\yes.js
```

The base-url in the config.php:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/mspn';
```

When I tried:

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url('tampilan/js/yes.js'); ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

When tried it in my browser, the script is not working. But when I checked the 'view-source' feature, and clicked on the link of that js, it pointed to the right file. So I guess the include function is correct.

I have done the `$autoload['helper'] = array('url');` in autoload.php. And done this `$this->load->helper('url');` in the controller file.

I did the include function for my css file, it worked. But it didn't for this js file.
Now, I've finally given up to feel like I know what did I do wrong. So what have I missed?
Thanks.

Comment: Watch our for case sensitivity, you're doing it wrong and you will have problems when migrating to a linux hosting.

Comment: I've tried that too, nothing changes.. What do I do?

Comment: are you sure you JS is working properly ?

Comment: IF you can click the url when viewing source and see the js, then the js is busted.. check your debugger

Comment: @user20232359723568423357842364, sorry, what you mean by that?

Comment: There is likely an issue in your JS file.

Comment: Load your page, open the developer tools in chrome or firefox, and go to the console to see if there are javascript errors.

Comment: I have checked the JS file, it worked. This application, I have built before, with the same code, without framework. Now I'm re-build it with CodeIgniter. Then this problem appears..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i am not expert in js but sometime i get this to, 
my experience check the script when load with firebug if run with firefox.
if you see

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a

```
NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/yourpath
```

to fix this Try putting your main library calls in your header tag before you call all your resources.

These should all still be in your header. Your document ready() stuff can stay in the footer. See if this fixes your issue.